# maven to use local jar in repository and not go to remote repo

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3

Setup:

```
Project A
Project B
Project A use Project B as dependency
```

via parent's mechanism (they both go to top level parent which has all dependencies defined in it). They have their own parent hierarchy too.
I would like to use locally built Project B and force maven to use that rather than pulling from Remote repo (we use nexus). I have tried -o option but it does not work. What's the best way for maven to stop looking for remote dependency and use locally built dependency to test local changes before committing.

EDIT - adding XMLs for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 ...">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.rockoder.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-main-iteration-01-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>myproject Top Parent</name>
  <description>This is the root of all projects. Versions and metadata are being specified here</description>
  <scm... </scm>
  <distributionManagement>...</distributionManagement>
  <properties>...</properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
     ....  
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rockoder.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-01-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>    
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rockoder.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-01-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <repositories>...</repositories>
  <pluginRepositories> .... </pluginRepositories>
  <build>....</build>
  <profiles>...</profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Something else must be wrong. Maven looks at your Maven repo before searching remote repo. Are you running Maven from the parent project?

Comment: @Tunaki I am running maven install target at Project's A level. Can't do it at parent since parent's pom only has sub-modules defined in it. Code is at Project's A level. So the parent basically defines all dependencies in one places to eliminate dups and to build all sub-modules. But in local-testing (we deploy stuff on tomcat eventually) we build and test local changes before committing to source control system and some process builds maven artifacts automatically.

Comment: Use snapshot version

Comment: mvn. adding pom.xml will take time since i have complex heirarchy going up to parent. What i described in response to Tunaki's comments should be good to clarify. I will try to add structure later.

Comment: You can run `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` from parent which has only modules defines...

Answer (score 1):

As @Tunaki commented: you have to install your parent POM, to be sure, that all modules are built, see [Maven by Example - Chapter 6. A Multi-Module Project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html):

> With the `simple-weather` project containing all WAR file. To do this, you will want to compile and install both projects in the appropriate order; since `simple-webapp` depends on `simple-weather`, the `simple-weather` JAR needs to be created before the `simple-webapp` project can compile. To do this, you will run mvn clean install command from the `simple-parent` project:

If you don't install your parent POM, you have to install first your Project B POM and then your Project A POM.

Maven will only load dependencies from remote repository, if dependencies are not in your local repository or a newer `SNAPSHOT` version is present in remote repository, see [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html):

> Downloading in Maven is triggered by a project declaring a dependency that is not present in the local repository (or for a `SNAPSHOT`, when the remote repository contains one that is newer). By default, Maven will download from the central repository.

Comment: I was trying to add my poms as asked by someone above but it was too much of effort since the poms are massive and i had to strip a lot. I have tried the option mentioned in above answer which is to build parent, build and test and did not work. I will retry your suggestion. In the meanwhile, it is clear that this is a valid question and most likely faced by many so please Upvote this question.

Comment: So it turned out to be a code issue. Basically I found that by installing Dependent module B locally (and making sure .m2 is cleaned up) and building A (which depends on B) it does *pick up* local B and does not go to remote. Main problem with my code was it has some outdated module of same name which was actually overriding my changes and I was thinking remote is overriding it.